# Modal using PHP/MySQL not showing correct overlay content

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

I have a modal that only sort of works: http://onesourcepress.com/contemplations/archives.php

Clicking any of the date links brings up an overlay that uses the same image each time instead of the image associated with the date. The correct images are shown in the source code of the page, but they're just not popping up.

Here is the PHP code I'm using:

```php
<?php do { ?>
<span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">
<p class="text-center" style="font-size:24px; padding:0 0 0 0; line-height:80%">
<?php echo $row_rsDateList['newdate']; ?>
<span style="margin-left: -6px; margin-top:-0px; line-height:130%; font-size: 10px; vertical-align:text-top;">
<?php echo $row_rsDateList['shortyear']; ?></span></p></span>
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
<div class="overlay-content"><img src='imgs/<?php echo $row_rsDateList['meds_file']; ?>' class="img-responsive">
</div>
</div>
<script>
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";}
function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";}
</script>
<?php } while ($row_rsDateList = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsDateList)); ?>
```

Comment: And I just added the record ID to each so they have distinct IDs. As in: id="myNav14". Still doesn't work.

Comment: Got it to work using Bootstrap modal. So, never mind.